# Why union static members not stored as a union?

Tags: c++, unions, static-members

In C++ `union` can contain static members which, as in the case of classes, belong to a class and therefore are common to all objects.

```
union U
{
   long l;
   int i;
   static long sl;
   static int si;
};

int U::si;
long U::sl;
```

It would be logical to expect that all the union static members stored at the same address similar to non-static members storing. But it is not. A simple example shows that static members are stored under different addresses and can contain **independent** values.

```
int main()
{
   U u;
   u.si = 10;
   u.sl = 50;

   std::cout << "Non-static members adresses: " << &u.i << " " << &u.l << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Static members adresses: " << &u.si << " " << &u.sl << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Static members values: " << u.si << " " << u.sl << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Non-static members adresses: 006FF8EC 006FF8EC
Static members adresses: 00AEB144 00AEB140
Static members values: 10 50
```

I do not understand why independent values storing was left in unions. I think this is misleading and makes no sense. Nevertheless, it seems to me that there are reasons for this. What purpose of `union` static members?

Comment: "It would be logical to expect that the union static members storing is identical as for non-static members" - says who? That's not how classes work.

Comment: A union is a class type.  So it has static members like class types and they behave the same.

Comment: Why would it be logical to assume such a thing? That would mean each instance has it's own copy of the static member and thus are not shared between all instances.

Comment: @NeilButterworth What is the purpose of different stoting logic?

Comment: I think you guys misunderstood the question. It is obvious that the static and non-static members will not be at the same address as each other, but the OP seems to want to know why the two static members do not share an address.

Comment: So essentially you want a static data member that is a union between type A and B ?

Comment: @Brian, You are absolutely right!

Comment: Because, as you said " as in the case of classes, belong to a class and therefore are common to all objects"

Comment: "You are absolutely right! " - so create a static variable of a union type.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, your argument doesn't sound convincing

Comment: @DmytroDadyka If that was the case then for all instances it either has to be int or long. cant be int for some and long for others.

Comment: It may not be "convincing", but it's what the language standard says is the case.

Comment: Also the way it is implemented, this gives you more options. If you want them to behave as a union then have a static variable of union type. However if it was implemented as you expected you wouldn't be able to have two different static values

Comment: @NeilButterworth, It would be great if you quoted the standard in response to a question.

Comment: To make it simple, you may think your static variable is stored inside your union... but its not, that's why you have to add `int U::si;` or you get a linker error that your variable is not referenced and that's where the variable is actually stored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look at this from two perspectives.

### The C++ Perspective:

A union is, first and foremost, a class. It has a purpose distinct from a class, but it is informed by what a class is.

A union is a class for which only one of its subobjects is active at any one type. To this end, it changes how member subobjects of unions work. This is also part of why unions can't have *base class* subobjects.

Static data members are not member subobjects, so their disposition in a union should be no different from their disposition in a non-union class.

Furthermore, static members of types in C++ are really just a scoping mechanism for function and object names. They're still effectively global, but they can be private and hidden, and they have to be prefixed by their typename in order for you to use them.

It doesn't really make sense for static data members of a union to behave any differently from static data members of a class.

### The C++-must-be-compatible-with-C Perspective:

Unions exist in C, so C++ has to have them too. But unions are difficult to define within the C++ object model, painful to work with, and a lot of other things. So you can think of unions as a thing that C++ needs to have but would rather not deal with. So how do you deal with them?

You make unions work like C when dealing with the way C unions work. There is no such thing in C as a static member, so there's no C code out there expecting static union members to be combined. Therefore... don't combine them. If the user genuinely needs a static member that is a union of some set of types, they can easily create a union and make a single static member of that type.

So the user doesn't lose any expressive power by making static members different.

Comment: Your answer answers the question on the merits. Vote it.

Comment: It does not explain why it was decided to keep them that way. They could have been split from classes and keep them very restricted, as the C unions were at the time and still are. And, actually, that would have made a lot of sense and prevent a lot of complexity in C++. But they made them classes, and here we are... Also, it is important to note that C++ unions were not really kept compatible with C ones due to the active member shenanigans (even if compilers typically deviate there to avoid breaking people's code). So, in the end, we got more complexity and no real C compatibility.

Comment: @Acorn: "*They could have been split from classes and keep them very restricted, as the C unions were at the time and still are.*" That would create greater complexity, as you now have to deal with another distinct kind of type: a union that is distinct from class. Look at the standard, and you'll find that there are a *lot* of places that say "class" which currently apply to both class and union. What you would do would require replacing most of them with "class and union", all for the sake of a few instances where they are different.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not really. The actual complexity of the language (even if not in wording) would have been way smaller, and we wouldn't have to care anymore about unions when thinking about new features for classes and templates. The same way it would have been very nice to keep structs as they were (pure PODs, no methods, etc.), and only use `class` for actual classes. You are saying something very similar to what I was explaining in the comments of my own answer (take a look! :), but the difference is that you argue that the wording would have been more complex even in that case.

Comment: @Acorn: "*we wouldn't have to care anymore about unions when thinking about new features for classes and templates*" But that also means you wouldn't be able to have a template union. Why would you want to prevent that? That kind of thinking, that different features shouldn't interact even if the interaction is natural, obvious, and useful just because of some notion of "purity", is not a good thing. And look at what we would have with your POD suggestion: no trivially-copyable types, so if you need any kind of control or data hiding, you can't get that benefit, even if you *should*.

Comment: @NicolBolas I wouldn't miss templated unions, to be honest; and you could get them in other ways (e.g. inside a class template). Further, about: "the interaction is natural, obvious, and useful". It isn't natural, and not obvious. Even your own answer implies it: "unions are difficult to define within the C++ object model, painful to work with, and a lot of other things".

Comment: @NicolBolas Furthermore, this has nothing to do with "purity". Quite the opposite: you are the one being "too pure" and trying to get all the possible combinations of features, just because "why not", disregarding all complexity considerations. "*That kind of thinking (...) is not a good thing*" Really? I will ignore that...

Comment: @NicolBolas Finally, you claim we "should" have those benefits, without any discussion. Sorry, but that is your claim, not everyone's. Most languages designers do not agree with unbounded complexity. Not even Stroustrup is happy with C++'s. For instance, there is zero need for data hiding in unions, specially when you can embed them in classes. Even access control in OOP is disputed: Python, for one, does not even have it. As for trivially-copyable types, I don't see why you would lose them or what you are implying.

Comment: @Acorn: "*Further, about: "the interaction is natural, obvious, and useful". It isn't natural, and not obvious.*" The interaction under discussion certainly is. Unions change how member subobjects work; static members aren't subobjects, so how they work is "natural, obvious, and useful". For example, I can pass a union to a template that takes a type and will access some static member of it. I couldn't do that in your segregated world where unions and classes are fundamentally different even though they're basically the same.

Comment: @Acorn: "*Most languages designers do not agree with unbounded complexity.*" But since we're not talking about complexity, that's a non-sequitur. Making unions be classes with a few special rules *decreases* complexity. 90% of the questions you can ask about a union can be answered by looking at the answer for classes, because unions *are classes*. Similarly, giving special rules to things declared `struct` increases complexity, because you now have to remember those rules. As it currently stands, you only have to remember one: default public vs. private.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191363/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-acorn).

Answer (score 2):

Unions are classes that hold at most one data member at a time [[basic.compound]p1.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#1.6) [[class]p7](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#7) [[class.union]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#union), and there are no special rules for their static data members w.r.t. the rest of class types (i.e. `class` and `struct`).

Therefore, the static data members behave the same as in all classes.

If you want to have a static data member that is the union of several types, you could do something like:

```
union U {
    long l;
    int i;

    union {
        long l;
        int i;
    } static s;
};

decltype(U::s) U::s;

// They are the same indeed
static_assert(&U().s.l == &U().s.l);
```

You will need to refer to the elements via `s`, e.g. `s.l` instead of `sl`, though.

Comment: My question is not about practice, but about concept. I wonder why mechanisms are different. What made the authors of the standard apply various approaches? If it was impossible to leave the same logic, why were static union members even added?

Comment: @DmytroDadyka Hard to say without asking the original designers. However, it is clear that unions were modeled based on classes, and therefore inherit their behavior, which is what I tried to explain in the answer. In C, they are also specified basically together to structs, too; so one can imagine they just started from C wording and continued to model them together. Then, when static data members were added to classes, they got automatically added to unions as well.

Comment: @Acorn "and therefore inherit their behavior, " But this is not so for many union properties. Why is the exception not made in this case?

Comment: @DmytroDadyka Imagine you are a designer of C++ and you need to decide about rules for unions. There are multiple options, so you need to choose some. Creators of C++ chose one, you would choose an other one (which is "better" is a matter of opinion). For example, I can understand their choice, they wanted static members to behave all the same across different class types (classes, structs, and unions).

Comment: @DmytroDadyka I am not sure what you mean "for many union properties". There aren't really many differences. Take a look at [class] in the C++17 standard, there are some rules that slightly change for unions here and there, and then a section in [class.union]; but that's about it.

Comment: @DanielLangr, so your opinion - either of the two options would be correct. It seemed to me that only one of the options was acceptable and there were reasons for this.  I wanted to understand this reasons.

Comment: @Acorn, I mean inheritance, non-static members storage etc... classes and unions are different in many ways. But the logic of static members was left for some reason.

Comment: @DmytroDadyka Yes, those limits for unions are described in [class.union]p3, but it is simpler to do that than copy-pasting [class] into another [union] section and then replace everywhere `class` for `union`, even if you can remove a lot of stuff regarding inheritance. Then there is also the matter of mentioning them everywhere a class type is now mentioned, etc. I am not saying that the language should or shouldn't have been way simpler if unions were simply restricted to having data members and not being "true classes" with constructors, methods, etc., but...

Comment: @DmytroDadyka Why do you think that only one option was acceptable?

Comment: @DmytroDadyka • `union` is how you make those things union-ify.  If static class members by default union-ified for a `union`, how would you specify non-union-ifying statics?  That would be odd, since there is already a good pattern for doing a `union` (as Acorn described in the answer above).

Comment: @DanielLangr, unions were added to the standard with a well-defined goal their logic is completely transparent - members are at the same address.  But static union members is completely incomprehensible to me. The logic of their work contradicts the logic of the union's - they are not united, although they are in union. I'm sure it was done for a purpose, and not just "because".